# How to write BigQuery/SQL query to divide average of a column in one table from column in second/another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for SQL query to SELECT ratio of Value1/Value2 from two tables as below..

Table_1:
-------

```
 id  Type  Count          
            
1.   A.      2            
2.   B.      3             
3.   A.      1
4.   A.      4
5.   B.      2
```

### Table_2:

```
id  Type   Max 
1.   A.     10
2.   B.     10

where Value1 = SELECT  AVG(Count) FROM Table_1 GROUP BY Type

and   Value2 = SELECT Max FROM Table_2.
```

I tried below query

```
WITH table1 (SELECT AVG(Count) as avg_cnt...), 
     table2 (SELECT Max as max_val....)
     SELECT table1.avg_cnt/table2.max_val
     FROM ..
```

But it did not work.

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just aggregate and calculate:

```
select t2.type, avg(t1.count) / t2.max
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.type = t2.type
group by t2.type, t2.max;
```

No subqueries or CTEs are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `join`

```
Select cnt/maxval
from
(
select type,avg(count) cnt 
from table1
group by type
)A join table2 on table1.type=table2.type
```